# Android custom interpolator

Tags: android, interpolation

I have to animate my view like that it decelerate upto 30% after that accelerate till 70% and at last again decelerate till finish.

Please find below image for the function of time.

[image]

Which interpolater i have to used or need to go with custom one.

If custom one required then please let me know the function which i have to use in **getInterpolation**()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Defintely custom, can you post your equation for this image?

Comment: @petey this curve i created in paint; i need this type of animation; i don't know the equation...i am looking for the same.

Comment: I see, http://easings.net/ and http://www.dzone.com/snippets/robert-penner-easing-equations should be of help then.

Comment: that's looks logarithmic

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to write your own custom interpolator, you can use this library https://github.com/daimajia/AnimationEasingFunctions, use [ExpoEaseOut](http://easings.net/#easeOutExpo)

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
         Glider.glide(Skill.ExpoEaseOut, 300, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget, "translationY", 0, 100)
 );
set.setDuration(300);
set.start();
```

Comment: .@Mostafa Gazar,i'll try this and once it'll be helpful for me i'll accept the answer but really this seems to be useful so that i am giving upvote